# Aggregating python dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, summary

I have the following list, which is composed of multiple dictionaries (2 in this case for simplicity).

```
bz_list = [{'ID': 't1', 'WordCount':2},{'ID': 't2','WordCount':5}]
```

In Python, I want to sum the 'WordCount' field across the entire list.  I was expecting something like this to work.

```
[sum(item['WordCount']) for item in bz_list]
```

However, I receive the following error message - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Any ideas on how to achieve this goal?  Thank you in advance.

- Bill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) should be done against word counts (iterable), not on a single word count (int):

```
>>> bz_list = [{'ID': 't1', 'WordCount':2},{'ID': 't2','WordCount':5}]
>>> sum(x['WordCount'] for x in bz_list)
7
```

Answer (score 2):

How about summarizing the list, and not every member alone:

```
sum([item['WordCount'] for item in bz_list])
```

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) expects an iterable who's items can be added.